# MySQL pagination Limit

Tags: php, mysql

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-20, 20' at line 1

This is the error message I am getting. It worked when I searched for one of the items but returns this for all other items searched for. I know its something to do with my pagination.

Not sure if its to do with the records in the system as I dont have many test items yet. I have made sure that im not searching for anything that would appear in over half the results. I have been looking at this for a while now and dont know why the limit is wrong!

Here is my code.

```
 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY `$sortby` ASC")  or die(mysql_error());

///////////////////////////////////  Pagination Logic ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$nr = mysql_num_rows($sql); // Get total of Num rows from the database query
if (isset($_GET['pn'])) { // Get pn from URL vars if it is present
    $pn = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_GET['pn']); // filter everything but numbers for security(new)
    //$pn = ereg_replace("[^0-9]", "", $_GET['pn']); // filter everything but numbers for security(deprecated)
} else { // If the pn URL variable is not present force it to be value of page number 1
    $pn = 1;
} 
//This is where we set how many database items to show on each page 
$itemsPerPage = 20; 
// Get the value of the last page in the pagination result set
$lastPage = ceil($nr / $itemsPerPage);
// Be sure URL variable $pn(page number) is no lower than page 1 and no higher than $lastpage
if ($pn < 1) { // If it is less than 1
    $pn = 1; // force if to be 1
} else if ($pn > $lastPage) { // if it is greater than $lastpage
    $pn = $lastPage; // force it to be $lastpage's value
} 
// This creates the numbers to click in between the next and back buttons
// This section is explained well in the video that accompanies this script
$centerPages = "";
$sub1 = $pn - 1;
$sub2 = $pn - 2;
$add1 = $pn + 1;
$add2 = $pn + 2;
if ($pn == 1) {
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $pn . '</span> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $add1 . '">' . $add1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
} else if ($pn == $lastPage) {
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $sub1 . '">' . $sub1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $pn . '</span> &nbsp;';
} else if ($pn > 2 && $pn < ($lastPage - 1)) {
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $sub2 . '">' . $sub2 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $sub1 . '">' . $sub1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $pn . '</span> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $add1 . '">' . $add1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $add2 . '">' . $add2 . '</a> &nbsp;';
} else if ($pn > 1 && $pn < $lastPage) {
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $sub1 . '">' . $sub1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $pn . '</span> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $add1 . '">' . $add1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
}
// This line sets the "LIMIT" range... the 2 values we place to choose a range of rows from database in our query
$limit = 'LIMIT '.($pn - 1) * $itemsPerPage .', ' .$itemsPerPage; 
// Now we are going to run the same query as above but this time add $limit onto the end of the SQL syntax
// $sql2 is what we will use to fuel our while loop statement below
$sql2  = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY $sortby ASC $limit")  or die(mysql_error());
//////////////////////////////// END  Pagination Logic ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

///////////////////////////////////// Pagination Display Setup /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$paginationDisplay = ""; // Initialize the pagination output variable
// This code runs only if the last page variable is ot equal to 1, if it is only 1 page we require no paginated links to display
if ($lastPage != "1"){
    // This shows the user what page they are on, and the total number of pages
    $paginationDisplay .= 'Page <strong>' . $pn . '</strong> of ' . $lastPage. '&nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp; ';
    // If we are not on page 1 we can place the Back button
    if ($pn != 1) {
        $previous = $pn - 1;
        $paginationDisplay .=  '&nbsp;  <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $previous . '"> Back</a> ';
    } 
    // Lay in the clickable numbers display here between the Back and Next links
    $paginationDisplay .= '<span class="paginationNumbers">' . $centerPages . '</span>';
    // If we are not on the very last page we can place the Next button
    if ($pn != $lastPage) {
        $nextPage = $pn + 1;
        $paginationDisplay .=  '&nbsp;  <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $nextPage . '"> Next</a> ';
    } 
}
//////////////////////////////// END  Pagination Display Setup ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Sorry if its a big chunk of code :S any help would be great.

Comment: did you watch the video that came with the script?

Comment: `($pn - 1) * $itemsPerPage ` `$pn` is -1 so you are getting -20 for the first limit param.

Comment: @ByronWhitlock     if ($pn < 1) { $pn = 1; } so pn should be 0

Comment: @RobertH yeah I did it makes no mention of it. It works fine for displaying a set of results but not if I use a search

Answer (score 2):

```
// This line sets the "LIMIT" range... the 2 values we place to choose a range of rows from database in our query
$limit = 'LIMIT '.($pn - 1) * $itemsPerPage .', ' .$itemsPerPage;
```

this right here appears to be your problem...what happens if you are given page 0?  then it would be 0 - 1 * 20 = -20, 20

you can't have a negative offset...you need to change how your page number is properly interpreted, like if 0 for the $pn is detected then set it to 1?

Comment: higher in the code it forces the $pn to be one if it is lower than one     if ($pn < 1) { 
    $pn = 1;}

Answer (score 1):

It appears you may be doing LIMIT -20, 20 which is not a valid range.

$itemsPerPage should be positive numbers of a valid range such as 1 , 20

Also sanitize your data input with at least mysql_real_escape_string()

Please read about this here.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: higher in the code it forces the $pn to be one if it is lower than one if ($pn < 1) { $pn = 1;}

Comment: Change your line to say this and see if you still get your error. $limit = 'LIMIT 1, 20'

Comment: When I change it I dont get the error but the search returns no results

Comment: @Camimen change it to  $limit = 'LIMIT 0, 20' and works. but this does now mean that my pagination wont work

Comment: @Will this is called debugging.  We now know for sure that line is causing the problem.  Now look at your error and figure out what the problem with the line was before.  Something is either wrong with $pn or $itemsPerPage that is causing that value to come out as -20.